# Number of circles passing 4 points of n points in ellipse

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

For n points $(a \cos(t_k),b\sin(t_k))$ where $t_k=\frac{(2k-1)\pi}n, k=1,2,\cdots,n$ in ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$, I have found that there're many circles passing 4 of those points. It seems the number of circles passing through 4 of the n is to be [A008610[n-2]](https://oeis.org/A008610).
Or the number of necklaces with 4 black beads and n-3 white beads. For example for n=8, we could have 10 circles:
[image]

So the question is

1. Could we prove that the number of circles is A008610[n-2]?
2. Could we find more circles passing through 4 points with n points in an ellipse?

Comment: I have solved the 1st problem now that the answer is yes.
 The number of circles is equal to number of picking 4 different number k1,k2,k3,k4 from 1 to n so that n|2+k1+k2+k3+k4 which is equal to A008610[n-2]